# Does System Look and Feel change the element size?

Tags: java, swing, awt, look-and-feel

I want to write a Java-swing application and I don't want to use the default LaF (LookAndFeel). I know there is `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());`  to use the platform dependent LaF. I would actually like to use this. But I have one question:

Are buttons (or other elements) in some LaFs bigger or smaller than in other LaFs? So do I need to place all elements depending on the LaF or are all elements of equal size, independent of the LaF?

Answer (score 2):

> Are buttons (or other elements) in some LAFs bigger or smaller than in other LAFs?

Yes, it's very possible...

> So do I need to place all elements depenging on the LAF or are all elements of equal size, independent of the LAF?

This is what layout managers are for and why your should avoid using `setPreferred/minimum/maximum` size on most compnents...

Comment: Is there any good tutorial on how to use/write layout managers? Or should I just use the (awful) standard cross platform java design?

Comment: Take a look at [How to layout components in a container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for starters, this is fundamental concept of how Swing works